# Codeigniter and Tank_auth sending validation to view not working

Tags: codeigniter

Hi I am new to Codeigniter but have hit a brick wall.

I am trying to see if a user already exists.

First I upload the data via a form to a controller which does its validation etc but breaks on only that issue. I managed to find where it breaks but cant fix it from there.

*Prior to all this it querys the database finds there is in fact a match username and then reaches the snippet below*

```
      $errors = $this->tank_auth->get_error_message(); 
      //find the correct error msg

      foreach ($errors as $k => $v) $data['errors'][$k] =$this->lang->line($v);        
      //loop and find etc

      $temp_mess = $data['errors'][$k]; 
      //stores relevant stuff in the string
    }
  }
//echo $temp_mess; it outputs to the html so i can see it "says user exists"
$data['temp_mess'] = $tempmess; /// put this into a array

$this->load->view('layout', $data); ///send 
    }
}
```

Now for the view, it then calls the layout view etc but alas there is no output

```
$username1 = array(
        'name'  => 'username1',
        'id'    => 'username1',
        'value' => set_value('username1'),
        'maxlength' => $this->config->item('username_max_length', 'tank_auth'),
        'size'  => 30,
    );

<?php echo form_open('register', $form_reg_id ); ?>

<fieldset>
<legend align="center">Sign up</legend>
    <?php echo form_label('Username', $username1['id']); ?>
    <?php echo form_input($username1); ?>
    <?php $tempmess; ?>
    <div class="error"><?php echo form_error($username1['name']); ?>
    <?php echo isset($errors[$username1['name']])?$errors[$username1['name']]:''; ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</fieldset>
```

Thanks for any help on this

also could some one explain this line please. (for a really dumb person)

```
<?php echo isset($errors[$username1['name']])?$errors[$username1['name']]:''; ?>
```

Comment: Tank_auth isn't returning automatically an error when the username exists?

Comment: Thanks for your reply - it is returning to an array. I have just done an array dump and get this ["errors"]=> array(1) {["username"]=> string(76) "Username already exists. Please choose another username." }

Comment: My pleasure. Feel free to validate my answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tank_auth automatically returns an error when the username exists. Juste have to check the errors array.

Comment: Thanks again, you are correct as tank_auth does do a return array on usernames. But when you combine the register and login on to a single page it throws it off a bit. In the end I did this 
<?php echo "{$errors['username']}"; ?> 
instead of 
<?php echo isset($errors[$email1['name']])?$errors[$email1['name']]:''; ?> 
which is Tank_Auth's line.
I dont fully understand the last line of code. I know it pulls data out of the array but the above one is more simple and works so not sure why the next line is needed. It is solved now though